# What resistor is this?

Tags: resistors, identification

I'm trying to repair a BH04221 disco LED. The resistors to AC are broken, but I don't know what kind of resistors they are.

Can you help me?

[image: Resistor]

Comment: Have you considered that the BH04221 disco LED be what we call "beyond economical repair"?

Comment: Those resistors are in MELF package. It is impossible to determine the resistor value from the remains. And since resistors don't burn up without a reason, it means that the problem is elsewhere, and new resistors will likely burn up too, because something somewhere else is broken and needs replacing.

Comment: @Andyaka Yes, I have a new one but I wanted to know if i can repair it.

Comment: @Justme Thanks for your answer!

Comment: @JuanJoséOrtega If you have a new unit, open it up and determine the value. As stated, you need to find why the part turned in to smoke.